# How to get all running builds for current user in jenkins api?

Tags: jenkins

I know how to get all builds from a specific job and know how to get the list of builds from the current user in the Jenkins UI by going to `https://jenkins.${domain}.com/user/${username}/builds`, however, there doesn't seem to be an API for that specific address because if you go to `https://jenkins.${domain}.com/user/${username}/builds/api` it comes up with a 404.

Is there a way via the api to query all of the builds for a specific user?